# Directory function is called for in Emacs/elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I find the directory where a function is being called from?

For example, if I call the line

```
(defconst dir default-directory)
```

The value of dir is the directory where the fine containing the above line is, not the directory I am calling it from.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A function doesn't get called "from a directory", so your question makes little sense the way it is presently phrased. Are you asking how to find out, for a given function, the path to the elisp library which defines that function?

Comment: Currently I have a file (say in Desktop/) called foo.el which contains the line in the question, I am using that line in another file (say in Documents/) called bar.el

Currently the line returns "~/Desktop/", but I'd expect it to return "~/Documents/"

Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really -- what do you mean by "using that line in another file"? That sounds as if *both* files define `(defconst dir default-directory)`. In any case, `default-directory` is a buffer-local value which does not generally have anything to do with the location of a given elisp library. Its value will already be set by the time your elisp is loaded and evaluated, and (without taking steps to do otherwise) you'll get whatever the value happens to be for the buffer that was current when the code was evaluated.

Comment: For file-visiting buffers, `default-directory` will be the parent directory of the visited file. Otherwise it's simply inherited from the `default-directory` value at the time the buffer was created. (You can, of course, set the value manually; usually by calling `cd`).

Comment: Incidentally, I presume the name `dir` was just for the sake of example, but in case it wasn't: your `defconst` call defines a dynamic-scope variable (elisp doesn't *really* have constants), and you absolutely do not want to use a name like `dir` with no namespacing prefix for your dynamic variable names, as that's too liable to clash with temporary bindings in other code. If you were to compile that, the byte compiler would complain about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour in Emacs is to use the [directory](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html) associated with the [file being "visited" in the current buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html). 
So,

```
(file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))
```

should give you the directory name of the file of the current buffer (i.e., the one you are currently working with at the time, your custom Lisp function is called).

If you are not sure, whether your custom function is called in the context of a buffer, which already has a file name associated with it, you should test for this:

```
(let ((file (buffer-file-name)))
    (if (not file)
        (progn ... no file name here ...)
      ... ok, file name available ...))
```

Comment: When I use this like so:

(message (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))

I get the error "message: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil" 

Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexChesters: What's the current buffer (the one, which had the cursor) at the time, you execute the code? Is it one, which has an associated file name, or something like `*scratch*` (or `*Messages*`) which do not? For those buffers, `buffer-file-name` answers `nil`.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk! That was my problem, I was using it in a directory rather than an actual file.